# Jenkins API - buildWithParameters and fileParameter

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-api

so we're trying to use the Jenkins API to invoke a build with a file parameter.  Basically we're trying to give it the files to build in ZIP format.  We have a ZIP plugin installed to unzip the build file, but we can't get that far.

Basically we're trying to use the `buildWithParameters` endpoint, but based on scouring info available online combined with a test I have set up in Postman, it would seem that `buildWithParameters` only works with parameters that exist on the query string.

If we use the `build` endpoint, we're able to submit the file successfully, both in a node app we built (using the `request` library) and in Postman.  But if we roll back to `buildWithParameters`, using the same exact configuration, the file is not processed successfully by Jenkins (we get a file not found error).

Am I right about `buildWithParameters` only working with query string parameters?

To preempt why not just use the `build` endpoint: we need the build number back, which we get back from `buildWithParameters` but don't seem to get back with `build`.

To reiterate my question: is it possible to use the `buildWithParameters` endpoint and upload a file parameter?  It would seem like it is, but we have not been able to get it to work.